# jquery populate select list

Tags: jquery

I have this in my htm file

```
    <select id="SelItem">

    </select>
```

Within my javascript file I have a section for jquery I have the following

```
     var itemval= '<option value="OT">OT</option>';

     $("#SelItem").html(itemval);
```

Wouldn't the following populate my drop down with OT?
It does not populate anything in the drop down

Comment: [Looks fine to me.](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/zGFek/) Are you running the code on DOM ready?

Comment: Did you include `jQuery` on your page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to consider using [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
//Creates the item
var itemval= '<option value="OT">OT</option>';

//Appends it within your select element
$("#SelItem").append(itemval);​
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzwr7/)

## Update

As js1568 pointed out - the problem is most likely stemming from the page not being loaded when the JS / jQuery code is being executed. You should be able to fix this with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Creates the item
    var itemval= '<option value="OT">OT</option>';

    //Appends it within your select element
    $("#SelItem").append(itemval);​
});
```

Comment: If the code in the OP is not working, what makes you think this code would?

Comment: @MДΓΓ - I was providing an alternative option and a working example of it. It appears the issue is most likely directly related to when the JS is being called however, much like js1568 pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the page has loaded before running this code. Try wrapping your code inside `$(document).ready()` function.

[Introducing $(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the jquery is called, not what its doing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var itemval= '<option value="OT">OT</option>';
     $("#SelItem").html(itemval);
});
```